# How to avoid memory issues with Polars LazyFrames?

Tags: bigdata, parquet, python-polars

I am trying to process a large (but not excessively so) dataset using Polars LazyFrames. Even though I am streaming the results to disk using `sink_parquet`, the process dies very quickly after starting.

One quirk might be that I have a double join on the same LazyFrame for an inner, then left combination. I tried filtering beforehand instead, but it does not help.

One dataset is about 26M rows and takes up ~260MB as parquet. The other one is 4M rows / 50MB, and I have around 15G of free memory available. Plan is below; as far as I understand it, the entire query should be able to evaluate in streaming mode. Any ideas for diagnosing the issue?

[image]

Comment: You will probably need to provide a *"Reproducible example"* (and possibly talk to the Polars people directly e.g. on Discord/Github).

Comment: 26M rows * 4M rows might result in a lot of rows. I think it's important that in your query you cut down the data size as soon as possible.
Some example of input (as small as possible) / desired output + your current query would be a great starting point so we can see how it might be improved